# How do I fix my jQuery button slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have 3 images that I want to scroll through only when the "Next" or "Previous" buttons are clicked. So far I can't get it to hide the other images even. I'm stuck. If I just put one image in there it shows up where I want it to Stylesheets-wise, but I need to add the other two images and button scrolling.

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="carouselWrapper">

                <div class="carousel">

                    <div class="cImg active" >
                        <img src="../1.jpg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="cImg">
                        <img src="../2.jpg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="cImg">
                        <img src="../3.jpg">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="nav">
      <div id="button-previous">prev</div>
        <div id="button-next">next</div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('.active').show();

                $('#button-next').click(function(){

                $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                               if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
                    $('.cImg').first().addClass('active');
                    }
                    else{
                    $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
                    }
                $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
                $('.cImg').fadeOut();
                $('.active').fadeIn();


                });

                   $('#button-previous').click(function(){
                $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                       if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
                    $('.cImg').last().addClass('active');
                    }
                       else{
                $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
                       }
                $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
                $('.cImg').fadeOut();
                $('.active').fadeIn();
            });

        });
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.carousel img {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px 40px 80px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant CSS or set up a fiddle

Comment: @elzi I added the CSS I have for the img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're constraining the img to 40% width, but here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zezava/1/) I put together. Your javascript worked fine - didn't change a thing. Note the CSS changes, though:

```
.carouselWrapper {
  width:460px; // example height, use whatever you'd like
  height:300px; // example width, use whatever you'd like
  overflow:hidden;

  .carousel {
    width:auto;
    height:300px;
  }
  .cImg {
    float:left;
    width:460px;
    height:300px;
  }
}
```

Comment: How could I modify the CSS for the Next/Previous to center them inside the carousel to the left and right?

Comment: I'm not gonna do the whole thing for you... look into `position:absolute` for a hint though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exact solution you are looking for

```
<body>
<div class="slider-img">
<div>
<div class="back"><img src ="1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="back"><img src ="2.jpg" /></div>
<div class="back"><img src ="3.jpg" /></div>
<div class="back"><img src ="4.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<div id="button-next"><img src ="next.png" /></div>
<div id="button-pre"><img src ="previous.png" /></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Css for the above code is

```
.slider-img { width: 80%; margin:0px auto; height:500px;}
.back{position: absolute;}
#button-next{position:relative; float:right; top:220px; margin-right: 12px;}
#button-next:hover {opacity:0.4}
#button-pre{position:relative; float:left; top:220px;}
#button-pre:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Jquery

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".back").first().addClass("active");
    $(".back").hide();
    $(".active").show();
    $("#button-next").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("oldactive");
       if ( $('.oldactive').is(':last-child')) {

        $('.back').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else
        {
         $(".oldactive").next().addClass("active");
        }
     $(".oldactive").removeClass("oldactive");   
     $(".back").fadeOut("slow");
     $('.active').fadeIn("slow");

    });
 $("#button-pre").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("oldactive");
        if($('.oldactive').is(':first-child'))
        {
         $('.back').last().addClass('active');
        }
        else
        {
         $('.oldactive').prev().addClass('active');
        }
    $('.oldactive').removeClass('oldactive');
     $('.back').fadeOut("slow");
     $('.active').fadeIn("slow");
    });


   });


    </script>
```

I hope this will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Given that you didn't post your CSS, I'll just explain how I would do this.

First off, honestly, I would just find a jQuery or pure CSS carousel plugin and just use that in my code. Assuming we want something totally from scratch, that just cycles through images, I wouldn't even convolute it with multiple image tags. I would have one image tag, like below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="" id="carousel" />
</div>
```

And then I would just have jQuery code to cycle through images:

**Javascript**

```
var images = [
    "image/url/1.png",
    "image/url/2.png"
];

var selectedImage = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#carousel").attr("src", images[0]);
});

function goForward(){
    selectedImage += 1;

    if(selectedImage >= images.length){
        selectedImage = 0;
    }

    $("#carousel").attr("src", images[selectedImage]);
}

function goBackward(){
    selectedImage -= 1;

    if(selectedImage < 0){
        selectedImage = images.length - 1;
    }

    $("#carousel").attr("src", images[selectedImage]);
}
```

Then simply make buttons that call `goBackward();` and `goForward();` in my HTML anywhere, such as:

**More HTML**

```
<button onclick="goForward();">Forward</button>
<button onclick="goBackwward();">Backward</button>
```

Then you can style it however you want to get the image to look nice. You can also add custom jQuery animations and transitions to make the image look a little nicer as it transitions, but that's the basics.

**JSFiddle**

[Also check out my JSFiddle on this.](http://jsfiddle.net/imattie/x2jh07gb/)